# Using ViewData to pass string from Controller to View in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewdata

I am trying to pass a random `string`  from my `Controller` to the `View`.

Here is my `Controller` code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DisplayForm(UserView user)
    {
       //some  data processing over here
        ViewData["choice"] = "Apple";

        return RedirectToAction("Next", "Account");
    }
```

Now I want to pass that data value "Apple" to my view `Next.cshtml` which is created as follows:

```
//View: Next.cshtml

  @{
    ViewBag.Title = "Thanks for registering";
    Layout = "~/Content/orangeflower/_layout.cshtml";
   }
    <p>Your favorite fruit is:</p>@ViewData["choice"]
```

But I am not able to see my data in the browser when the project runs.

Here is the snapshot:

1) On debug, the controller showing the value:

[image]

2) The browser view doesn't show the value "Apple"

[image]

3) On further debug to my `Next.cshtml` View:
[image]

Why is the value not getting passed to the View correctly. Both my controllers for `Next` and `DisplayForm` are within the same Controller `AccountController.cs` , still value not getting displayed.

Can someone help me solve this ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are not rendering a view, you are redirecting. If you wanted to pass some information tyo the view you need to return this view after adding it to `ViewData`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayForm(UserView user)
{
    //some  data processing over here
    ViewData["choice"] = "Apple";

    return View();
}
```

If you want to pass a message that will survive after a redirect you could use `TempData` instead of `ViewData`.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DisplayForm(UserView user)
{
    //some  data processing over here
    TempData["choice"] = "Apple";

    return RedirectToAction("Next", "Account");
}
```

then inside the Next action you could fetch the data from TempData and store it inside ViewData so that the view can read it.

Comment: ohh so I need to write return View("Next","Account") as per my code right if I am not redirecting ?

Comment: @ParthDoshi, yes, if you want to use ViewData directly. But if you want to keep the Redirect-After-Post pattern you could use TempData as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing a post - redirect - get.  The `ViewData` is being set for this request, which returns a redirect, clearing the `ViewData`, then another request happens which does not have the data.  Use `TempData` instead and it will be added to the `ViewData` automatically on the next request.

Comment: Thanks! Sometimes I feel StackOverflow should allow us to accept two answers, one primary and the other as a secondary answer. Although, I got an answer from another user, I felt your answer was also good enough for me to understand the mistake in my code, so thanks for the quick reply